# Magento 2 Payment Method error bad request 400

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, error-log

When I try to pay with Mastercard credit card module I get an error

> bad request 400

If I go to my `var/log/exception.log` file I receive the following error:

```
main.CRITICAL: The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly at /var/www/html/emall/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php:641)"} []
```

I have tried many commands found in Internet, but I don´t know if the problem is with composer or with the module itself. 
This is the module that im using: https://marketplace.magento.com/ontap-module-mastercard.html

Hope someone can help.
Thank you and regards!

Comment: Your magento version please.

Comment: Hello. I`m using Magento 2.2.

Comment: Have you enabled debug mode and can you able to see the request and response details in payment log?

Comment: sorry its a little bit late. But yes, i have enabled debug mode and in Payment Log I see Authentication_Successful. It connects with Mastercard successfully , but it does not perform the transaction.

Comment: So can you please check the configurations on both side to see if there is no error in configuration

Comment: what do you mean to check on bot side? this are the last lines of response that I get 'response' => 
    array (
      '3DSecure' => 
      array (
        'gatewayCode' => 'AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESSFUL',
      ),
    ),
  ),
) [] []

Answer (score 0):

after trying a lot of thing I found the solution, in case you have the same problem than me.

I just setEnv the composer variable in .htaccess of the store.
Add this line at the top of your MagentoRootfolder/.htaccess file

```
SetEnv COMPOSER_HOME COMPOSER_HOME=~/.composer
```